# How to override the CSS scroll behavior with scrollTo in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have scroll smooth by default, but for one JavaScript scrollTo() command I'd like to override the CSS 'smooth' behavior and use auto, but the JS won't override the CSS.

What can I do?

Comment: does the scroll smooth css have `!important` added?

Comment: @Sachi.Dila it does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the inline style of your container's scroll to `auto`, then reverting the change by altering the value of `html.style.scrollBehavior` before and after scrolling programmatically. JS's [`ScrollToOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions)'s `behavior` key-value pair cannot override CSS's `scroll-behavior`. The [CSSOM draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#scrolling) mentions this:

> If the user agent honors the scroll-behavior property and one of the following are true:
>
> • behavior is "auto" and element is not null and its computed value of
>   the scroll-behavior property is smooth
>
> • behavior is smooth
>
> ...then perform a smooth scroll of box to position. Otherwise, perform an instant scroll of box to position.

Your user agent honors the `scroll-behavior` property; this means that we're going to check one of the two conditions. When you're using `window.scroll({..., behavior: 'auto'})`, we're entering the first condition. The `behavior` we're setting is indeed `auto`, element is indeed not `null`, and the computed value of `scroll-behavior` property is indeed `smooth`. Therefore, a smooth scroll will happen. To make the condition false, we can override the computed value of the `scroll-behavior` property to `auto` by using an inline style.

Here's a simple example. Scroll programmatically without smooth behavior by clicking the `Scroll down 200` button. Scroll smoothly by clicking the links.

```js
function scrollNoSmooth() {
  // Setting inline style of scroll-behavior to 'auto' temporarily
  html.style.scrollBehavior = 'auto'
  
  // This 'behavior' cannot override the CSS 'scroll-behavior'
  // Do scroll
  window.scroll({
    top: window.scrollY + 200,
    left: 0,
    // behavior: 'smooth'
  })
  
  // Reverting inline style to empty
  html.style.scrollBehavior = ''
}

const html = document.querySelector('html')
const fixed = document.querySelector('.fixed')

fixed.addEventListener('click', scrollNoSmooth)
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.fixed {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #121212;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">Scroll down 200</div>
<a name="A" href="#B">A</a>
<a name="B" href="#C">B</a>
<a name="C" href="#A">C</a>
```

Comment: Genius! You rock : )

Answer (score 3):

If you only have to support chrome and/or firefox, you can use an undocumented 'behavior: instant' value to override the scroll behavior set by css, more at https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/2719.
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/fr7m40kw/

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const container = document.querySelector('.container')
    container.scrollTo({
    top: container.scrollTop + 100,
    behavior: 'instant'
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #AAD;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<button>
 Scroll
</button>
```