# Is there a way to force scroll behavior `auto` even if the scroll behavior is defined `smooth` on the html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I would like to have the scroll behavior `auto`. The problem is that within my project the scroll behavior is set to smooth on a global level e.g.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

I would like to invoke the window.scrollTo() with the behavior `auto`.

```js
window.scrollTo({
  top: 500,
  behavior: "auto"
});
```

The problem is it always takes the behavior defined in the css even if I define it differently in the js. Is there a way to force the browser to use the `auto` when invoked through js behavior?

Comment: did you try `unset`? or `!important`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override the CSS scroll behavior with scrollTo in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795723/how-to-override-the-css-scroll-behavior-with-scrollto-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `!important` css property, like this:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: auto !important;
}
```

This will prevent overwriting this value in other css definitions.

The importance of your CSS is determined (partially) based on where your CSS style is defined.
The order in which importance is determined is (least important to most important):

- external css file `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"`
- internal css style `<style></style>`
- inline css `<div style="">`

So when defining a css style in a seperate file, and another style with the exact same selector in as an internal stylesheet, the style in the internal sheet is used. Using `!important` in the external sheet will then force that style and will make it so the internal css style is overwritten.

---

If you can't add styling through css files or by editing the HTML, you can also set the style by using JavaScript, like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.scrollBehavior = "auto !important";
```

Comment: So what I don't want to do is redefine the global style to be 'auto'. I only want the scroll behavior to be auto in one specific case and the rest should stay smooth.

Comment: Where you are calling `window.scrollTo({`, you could add the example code in the last line of my answer post. This should set the scrollBehavior to auto. When you want te revert it to smooth, you can call the same code, but with smooth instead of auto.

Or you could dynamically add a class to your html tag. Define a styling for .html.auto-scoll or something like that. Then add the class auto-scroll to the html tag using javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up seeing that this question is a duplicate from another one. Changing the style globally before and after the scroll seems to be the way to go.